# Given the moment generating function, find the distribution of $X$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with $M_X(t)=\frac{3}{3-t}$ $t \in (-3,3)$.

Now how do I find the distribution of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $Y$ has an exponential distribution i.e. has density $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq 0$, then its moment generating function is given by
$$
Ee^{tY}=\int_0^\infty e^{ty} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \,dy=
\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda-t)y}  \,dy=
\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t};\quad (t<\lambda).
$$
Now use the uniqueness of moment generating functions to determine the distribution of $X$ in your case.